# Xamarin.UWP sets the Entry.Text to null when the Entry looses focus. How can I get the value of Entry.Text before it is set to null

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin forms application in which I am trying to do some processing with the `Entry.Text` property whenever the Entry looses focus (ie in the **Entry.UnFocus EventHandler**).

However, I have noticed that Xamarin is setting the value of `Entry.Text` to `null` whenever the entry looses focus, and it does this before calling triggering the `Unfocus` event. So I have a situation where he `TextChanged EventHandler` receives a `e.NewTextValue` of `null`, and the `Entry.IsFocused` is still `true`, after which the `Unfocus EventHandler` is then triggered.

This breaks my app as the order of events is very different on Android on ios. For one `entry.Text` is not set to null whenever an entry looses focus.

So my question is how can I get the value of Entry.Text when the entry looses focus before it gets set to null?

Comment: Please add to your question the exact code that you tried. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then someone can determine exactly what in that code results in the symptom, and how to change the code to get the desired result.

Comment: Ok I will do that, I was hoping my description would be enough, as the code is a little time consuming to isolate. But I will do that and update the question.

Comment: I test on UWP just with a simple Entry and override the event `Unfocused` and `TextChanged` , when the entry is losing focus , `TextChanged` never triggers ,`Entry.Text` is not set to null , could you provide the code snippet which could reproduce the problem ?